# Using INDEX/MATCH to return a value from a set of tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having a hard time writing an `INDEX`/`MATCH` formula. I need the formula to look through multiple rows to find the one that matches my lookup value. I have multiple headers for different months.

The current formula I have in cell `B2` is:

```
=INDEX($D5:$M5,MATCH($B$1,$D$4:$M$4,0))
```

As you can see, if I type `January` in `B1`, `B2` displays `a`. If I type `February`I would like it to display `99`.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Apart from multiple headers, within a header you have multiple values, e.g. For February it starts in D10 and ends in M11, so which values should be returned?

Comment: Are there more conditionals?

Comment: You have ten data columns for each month, and two key values, Pearl District and Hollywood, associated with all of the data.  When you enter January, how is Excel supposed to know which of the 20 January values to select?  There's a lot of missing explanation needed to understand the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous questions, it looks like you are trying to extract the data for a specific column given *two* lookup criteria - the Month and the Branch.

For simplicity's sake, I'm also assuming that the Branches are exactly the same for each sub-table, i.e they all exist and are in the same order.

With your worksheet modified as follows,

[image: Animated worksheet screen-cap showing the lookup Month being modified, the lookup Branch being modified, plus the formula being filled to the right]

enter the following formula in `B3`:

```dart
=INDEX(D4:D16,MATCH($B$1,$D$4:$D$16,0)+MATCH($B$2,$C$4:$C$16,0)-1)
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of indexing into a row, the formula indexes into the required data column, i.e. `D4:D16`.

The first `MATCH()` finds the matching Month row, whilst the second one finds the offset to the matching Branch. The `-1` is required to convert the one-based index returned by the second `MATCH()` to a zero-based offset. (And yes,`MATCH($B$2,$C$4:$C$16,0)-1` could have been replaced by `MATCH($B$2,$C$5:$C$16,0)`, but it is easier to understand with the `-1`.)

**Notes:**

- The way the formula has been written means that filling the formula to the right extracts the next column's value. That's why the `D4:D16` is a relative reference.
- Alternatively, to obtain another column's data, just replace the `D4:D16` with the appropriate reference. (The absolute reference, `$D$4:$D$16`, needs to remain unchanged if a single Month header is used, as explained next.)
- Multiple headers for each month are not required, even when extracting data from a column other than the first one. Only the first data column needs one or, alternatively, a merged header can be used instead. (This is why the `$D$4:$D$16` is an absolute reference.)

Answer (score -2):

**My answer have two options:**

1. Using Data Set shown in Screen Shot.
2. Solution with modified Data Set.

**Option 1:**

*I would like to suggest a method, which comprises a simple trick to manage different data sets according to the Month.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- You need to create **Helper Cell** in `B41`, which reflects **Month's Name** in Cell `B42`.
- Formula in Cell `B42`:

`=IF(OR(B41=1,B41=2,B41=3,B41=4,B41=5,B41,6),CHOOSE(B41,"January","February","March","April","May","June"))`

- Formula in Cell `B43`, drag it Down.

`=IF($B$41=1,INDEX($B34:$L34,MATCH(B$42,$B$33:$L$33,0)),IF($B$41=2,INDEX($B38:$L38,MATCH(B$42,$B$37:$L$37,0)),""))`

**Note:**

- *Second Formula need to be extended as soon rest of month's data included.*

**Option 2:**

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `B51` & fill it Down

  `=INDEX($B47:$G47,MATCH($B$50,$B$46:$G$46,0))`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Just write your concern,, Y down voted ??